# Mocha: Error Timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, es6-promise

I am trying to seed the database for unit test.

Below is the `seed.js` file:

```
.......
const app = require('./app')
const db = app.get('db')

const saveUsersToDB = (done) => {
    db.User.bulkCreate(users)
         .then(() => (done))
}

module.exports = {saveUsersToDB};
```

My `app.test.js` file:

```
.......
const expect = require('expect')
const request = require('supertest')
const {saveUsersToDB} = require('./seed/seed');

before(saveUsersToDB)
```

When I run the test below is the error I get:

```
Express listening on port 3000!
  1) "before all" hook: saveUsersToDB

  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook: saveUsersToDB:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I thought returning `.then(() => (done))` was enough?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should be `.then(() => done())`.

Comment: Mocha also supports promises, so the spec can just return a promise.

Comment: I hope you would have got a working solution. I have answered it here with `before`. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200966/5375291

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `(done)` will actually return the function instead of invoking it. In order to call `done`, you need to write it this way.

```
.then(() => done())
```

However, I don't recommend using `done` along with promises. You just simply need to return the promise then `mocha` will handle it automatically.

```
const saveUsersToDB = () => db.User.bulkCreate(users)
```

Answer (score 24):

By default, Mocha tests have a 2 second timeout (which means that the test needs to be completed in 2 seconds).

You can increase it (in milliseconds) as follows:

```
this.timeout(5000); // this test can take up to 5 seconds
```

https://mochajs.org/#timeouts

Comment: Yeah but adjusting the timeout in this case isn't going to help.

Comment: Was looking at a bunch of answers on SO regarding this error - none of them working for me until I found this one.  Nice, Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I had the same isue. This error promps because the 2 seconds timeout, so if your test needs to connect to ddbb it will most provably surpas it.

What I did was to separate all my tests that needed somme kind of connection to external resources into my integration tests folder and then added the next flag in my `package.json` test script:

```
"int-test": "mocha --timeout 15000 tests/integration/**/*.test.js --compilers js:babel-register "
```

Follow this link for other ways to increase the timeout: [mocha timout](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts)