# For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have this test of nodejs when testing I get a error of done function not declared.

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
> My test code is, I have the done call back but still getting the error to call the `done();`

```
    it('remove existing subdocument', (done) => {
    const Vic = new User({
      name: 'Vic',
      posts: [{ title: 'Leaning Nodejs' }]
    });

    vic.save()
      .then(() => User.findOne({ name: 'Vic' }))
      .then((user) => {
        const post = user.posts[0];
        post.remove();
        return user.save();
      })
      .then(() => User.findOne({ name: 'Vic' }))
      .then((user) => {
        assert(user.posts.length === 0);
        done();
      });
  });
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that this same error can occur if the function you are testing does not return properly, or is just not a valid function at all

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, @MFAL's link in comment helped. I am expanding upon it.

When there is an error/incorrect assertion an error is raised inside the promise. This leads to promise rejection. Once rejected done is never called and mocha reports time out.
I solved this by writing a `.catch` block and chaining it with the promise:

```
          it('resolves', (done) => {
            fooAsyncPromise(arg1, arg2).then((res, body) => {
                expect(res.statusCode).equal(incorrectValue);
                done();
            }).catch(done);
         });
```

Other ways as mentioned in the [Wietse's blog](https://wietse.loves.engineering/testing-promises-with-mocha-90df8b7d2e35) are:

To chain a `then(done, done)` which handles both resolve and reject of the promise.

```
         it('resolves', (done) => {
           resolvingPromise.then( (result) => {
             expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved');
           }).then(done, done);
         });
```

Return a promise:

```
        it('resolves', () => {
          return resolvingPromise.then( (result) => {
            expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved');
          });
        });
```

Use async/wait:

```
        it('assertion success', async () => {
          const result = await resolvingPromise;
          expect(result).to.equal('promise resolved'); 
        });
```

Comment: Tried the first option but got:                                                                                                      else throw err
           ^

ReferenceError: done is not defined

Comment: well done is a argument variable in scope of the function, you should be able to get it. Are you passing the argument as `done`?

Comment: I'm using async/await but still experiencing this issue while testing LitElement Web Components using `@open-wc/testing` and Karma. I've had no issues doing it this way up until my latest component though. . . . I wonder what the differentiator is.

Comment: When you're catching the error use done(error) so Mocha actually reports an error has occurred.

Answer (score 105):

I know an ugly way of doing it, just by increasing default timeout of Mocha from  ***2 seconds to 10 seconds*** this can be done by adding a flag `--timeout 10000`  in the test scripts i.e -

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_ENV=dev && node server.js",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  }
```

Comment: This one worked for me, I had not changed any code, my test just suddenly started failing for no reason. My machine probably has just gone slow as compared to yesterday?

Comment: This solution works for local testing, but when I test on Travis.ci the tests fail. Whit the first answer the tests have success both locally and on Travis.ci

Answer (score 32):

You can just add timeout to the specific test to increase/override the default timeout which is 2 seconds. I had the same issue but was able to by pass it using:

```
it('Test', (done) => { 
//your code  
done();
}).timeout(10000);
```

Comment: Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.

Answer (score 10):

My problem was the timeout itself (extending it didn't help) so my solution was

```
it("it should test methods",function(){
     this.timeout(0);
   });
```

as you see you don't need the `done` argument

Answer (score 6):

If none of the above helps, try to get rid of "done" and use async function() instead

```
it("Test Post Request", async function () {
    _code_
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to increase the timeout.
Alternative way is to do that in required method only:

```
 it('remove existing subdocument', function(done) {
         this.timeout(10000);
      //your code is here
      done();
    });
```

That help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In `package.json` file
you can fix this error by using --timeout 15000, 
just like I use below.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server/server.js",
  "test": "export NODE_ENV=test || SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" && mocha --timeout 15000 server/**/*.test.js",
  "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
}
```

This error occurs because of mocha.

Comment: Looks like you're using 15000, not 1500

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting that error, and after several hours of researching and debugging, I found the root cause.

Consider this test:

```
const delay = require('delay')

describe('Test', function() {
    it('should resolve', async function(done) {
      await delay(1000)
    })
})
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Now consider this slightly different test, where the **done** argument is **removed**:

```
const delay = require('delay')

describe('Test', function() {
    it('should resolve', async function() {
      await delay(1000)
    })
})
```

When I run this test, it passes.

Somehow the presence of the **done** argument in the async function breaks the test, even if it's not used, and even if **done()** is called at the end of the test.

Using Mocha version **7.2.0**

Comment: This behavior is reasonably well outlined in the docs. See “asynchronous code” here https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add the timeout in `before` or `beforEach`.

```js
describe('new loading express', function () {

  before(function () {
    this.timeout(20000); // 20 second timeout for setup
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this error in the VS Code extenstion development, you need to add `timeout` to the Mocha instance in the `src/test/suite/index.ts`, for example:

```
// Create the mocha test
const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
    color: true,
    timeout: 10000 // Your application ideal timeout here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Error Message, in my case it was caused of the usage of `sinon.useFakeTimers()`

That call conflicts with the `setTimeout()` used in my code. After removing the that all worked fine.

Comment: For me, it worked only by removing sinon from project dependencies. It seems that sinon is mangling some timers. (I didn't used sinon so this is why I've removed it).

Answer (score 2):

Add these line in package.json file to increase the timeout

"scripts": {
"test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
},

Answer (score 1):

Happe with me when I returned back maintaining an old node-module from Node6 to Node 13. The fix is simple :

- adding a file `mocha.opts` under the folder of tests.
- The content of this file is one line : `--timeout 10000`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it is actually because I passed done and called done in then. So removing done makes the test pass. I was calling an `async` function in route I was testing

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Simon Boudrias here [Why am I getting "Error: Resolution method is overspecified"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761683/why-am-i-getting-error-resolution-method-is-overspecified) worked for me. I was missing just the `await Promise.resolve()` I initially thought by calling `after(async () => driver && driver.quit());` would have cleaned up everything and properly existed. Off course don't forget to set `.timeout(10000);` to whatever amount of time you need so that you are covered incase you need more than the default 2000 to run your test.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with

- async-await,
- return Promise-then,
- function(done)-done()

In every situation there are timeout for

- global timeout which can be given by command parameter as given below
- timeout for funcitons (before/after[each|all], it) given as chain method or parameter

  /usr/bin/node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -u bdd --colors /home/cemt/cli-js/test/**/*.spec.js

Test code:

```
describe('NSSF', function () {

    var a = 0

    beforeAll(async function () {
        console.log(">>> 1. a: ", a);
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var intt = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(">>> a: ", ++a);
                if (a == 10) {
                    clearInterval(intt)
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 800);
        });
    }, 12000);

    it('a should be set to 1', () => {
        console.log("-----1");
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            console.log("-----2");
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(1)
            }, 14000)
        }).then(a => {
            expect(a === 1);
        })
    }, 3000);
})
```

Without timeout setting:

[image]

With timeout setting:

```
/usr/bin/node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --slow 5000 -u bdd --timeout 10000 --colors /home/cemt/cli-js/test/**/*.spec.js
```

[image]

Launch.json in VS Code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the official Mocha page ([Mocha page](https://mochajs.org/#-timeout-ms-t-ms))-> use the next flag when starts mocha:

--timeout , -t 
Update in v6.0.0: --no-timeout is implied when invoking Mocha using inspect flags. It is equivalent to --timeout 0. --timeout 99999999 is no longer needed.

Specifies the test case timeout, defaulting to two (2) seconds (2000 milliseconds). Tests taking longer than this amount of time will be marked as failed.

To override you may pass the timeout in milliseconds, or a value with the s suffix, e.g., --timeout 2s and --timeout 2000 are equivalent.

To disable timeouts, use **--no-timeout.**

Note: synchronous (blocking) tests are also bound by the timeout, but they will not complete until the code stops blocking. Infinite loops will still be infinite loops!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had a `before` in my code. All it took to fix it was to add `this.timeout(0);` as the first line in the `before` function, and use async-await throughout the file and removing `done()`.

Answer (score 0):

If tests are longer than the time you have set, you will keep getting the error,  Updating **package.json** file, with ( adding the second test with **--no-timeout** attribute solved my issue.

"scripts": {

> ```
> "test": "cross-env PORT=8000 mocha --watch",
> "test": "cross-env PORT=8000 mocha --watch --no-timeout"*,
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Not need to add `done()`. Just extend mocha timeout globaly:

**Option 1:** In `package.json` add new property:

```
  "mocha": {
    "timeout": "10000"
  }
```

**Option 2:** Specify configuration file and add `timeout` option in it

i.e. `.mocharc.yml`

with entry: `timeout: '2000' # same as "timeout: '2s'"`

see examples: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.yml