# what should i do for error For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, supertest

I'm running a test using mocha

```
it('should allow a POST to /users', async function () {
        
        const res = await request.post('/users').send(firstUserBody);
    
        expect(res.status).to.equal(201);
        expect(res.body).not.to.be.empty;
        expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
        expect(res.body.id).to.be.a('string');
        firstUserIdTest = res.body.id;
        
    });
```

but i have an error

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

If I do it using done() the function is not async but it should be

```
it('should allow a POST to /users', async function (done) {

        const res = await request.post('/users').send(firstUserBody);

        expect(res.status).to.equal(201);
        expect(res.body).not.to.be.empty;
        expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
        expect(res.body.id).to.be.a('string');
        firstUserIdTest = res.body.id;
        done();
    });
```

what should i do ?

Comment: What do you mean it's not async?

Comment: I fixed code 2, if I make code like 2, 'await' gives an error.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: And _does_ the POST resolve in under 2s? Your test callbacks don't need to accept a done parameter if they're async.

Comment: idk but it seems dont. i have Timeout of 2000ms exceeded error

Comment: I hope you would have got a working solution. I have answered it here with `before`. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200966/5375291

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches of setting timeouts in Mocha:

(I would use a minimum of 20s when testing API calls)

1. Inside the test or describe block

   ```
   describe('a suite of tests', function() {
     this.timeout(20000);
     ...
   ```

   (be careful not to use an arrow function as that will cause `this.` to not work)

   See: https://mochajs.org/#timeouts
2. Config level - `.mocharc.js` file or flag during runtime `--timeout 20000` or even setting options with API (`mocha.setup()`).

   I prefer using `.mocharc.js.` where you can put something like:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     bail: true,
     timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minute timeout
     spec: ['specs/']
   };
   ```

Documentation and examples:

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js

https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs

https://mochajs.org/#-timeout-ms-t-ms

PS You should not need the `done()` with async functions